# Eliminate Duplicates of a List (Python)

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of lists and need to eliminate all lists that have the same 3rd element, and save 1.

For example:

```
x=[[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[5,6,3],[2,4,6],[8,5,9],[10,5,9]]
```

could turn into:

```
x=[[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[8,5,9]]
```

I've attempted a solution that eliminates all lists that have the same 2nd index using lambda, but I don't know how to save one of each element like set() does--I just get:

```
x=[[2,4,6]]
```

Comment: Please post your attempt so that we can tell you where it falls short

Comment: where did `[1,3,3]` and `[5,6,3]` go?

Comment: @roippi: Presumably, since the element at index 2 in both of those lists is 3, they disappeared because `[1, 2, 3]` was kept. It's not clear whether the OP means index 2 counting from 0, or second element counting from 1.

Comment: @user2357112 the "second element" is the element at index 1.

Comment: I meant index 2 counting from 0, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python sets should still work for you:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for s in x:
    e = s[2]
    if e not in seen:
        result.append(s)
        seen.add(e)


>>> result
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [8, 5, 9]]
```

Comment: I kept getting set() errors like "unhashable type: list", had no idea that you can just define a variable to be an empty set like that. TY!

Comment: Bah, with Raymond in play is not even fair :)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a `dict` here, which could be a bit more flexible later:

```
data =[[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[5,6,3],[2,4,6],[8,5,9],[10,5,9]]
one_of = {el[2]:el for el in data}.values()
# [[10, 5, 9], [5, 6, 3], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Jon, we ll get only the last duplicate value but he wants only the first duplicate value.

Comment: Just reverse the data if you want the first values.

Comment: @thefourtheye well... the first occurrence is a reasonable assumption, however, it's not actually specified that's the case :) *need to eliminate all lists that have the same 3rd element, and save 1*

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set` if you define a helper class

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[5,6,3],[2,4,6],[8,5,9],[10,5,9]]
>>> class Element(list):__hash__=lambda s:hash(s[2]);__eq__=lambda s,o:s[2]==o[2]
... 
>>> set(map(Element, L))
set([[8, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with list comprehension and helper set:

```
>>> t = set()
>>> y = [l for l in x if l[2] not in t and not t.add(l[2])]
>>> y
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [8, 5, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `itertools` docs come with a nice set of [recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), one of which, `unique_everseen` does exactly what you want: "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."

You can copy it paste it from the recipes, or you can [`pip install more-itertools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools) and just use it as `more_itertools.unique_everseen`.

Or you can look at the code, and see that it's essentially just a slightly more flexible and slightly optimized version of exactly what Raymond Hettinger's answer does.*

And that's exactly what the recipes are there for—when you want to do something to an iterable, there's often a recipe for it, which not only does what you want, but is so simple that if you take a couple minutes to work out how it works, you'll know how to do it yourself in the future.

---

* This shouldn't surprise anyone who knows anything about Python, or just looks at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c) to `itertools`…

Comment: @RomanPekar: In that case, I should have added a link to it. (Which I've now done.)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[5,6,3],[2,4,6],[8,5,9],[10,5,9]]
>>> s = set(i[2] for i in L) 
>>> [s.remove(i[2]) or i for i in L if i[2] in s]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [8, 5, 9]]
```